# Project Euler – Exercise 1

Tags: python, sum, range

I am trying to find the sum of all numbers less than 1000 divisible by 3 and 5. I have this so far:

```
for i in range(0, 1000):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print i
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        print i
b = sum(i)
print b
```

I get a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` (referring to `b = sum(i)`)

Comment: Is it `3 and 5`, or `3 or 5`?  You wrote 3 and 5 which is simply `divisible by 15` but your code implies `3 or 5`.

Comment: Good old Project Euler problem #1. It's much more beneficial if you work through them yourself. Also I wouldn't settle for the current answers if I were you - there's a neater way using arithmetic progression.

Comment: Try summing all numbers less than 1000, first. Get that right, then work on the additional constraints.

Comment: Printing i does not sum anything up.

Comment: Do you want all the numbers divisible by **either** 3 or 5, or just the numbers divisible by **both** 3 and 5?

Comment: The sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
# initially we declare a variable that will hold the current sum
# and at the end of the for it will hold 
# the sum of the numbers you have mentioned.
b = 0
for i in range(1000):
    # Then whether i is evenly divided by 3 or 5 
    # we add this number to the current sum
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        b += i

# last we print the sum
print b
```

Answer (score -1):

use the following line

sum takes an iterable object as input. List, sets, etc. are iterable.

So try the following

```
b = sum(i for i in range(1000) if i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0)
```

Comment: You do not need the brackets and it's faster without

Comment: @MaxNoe it faster with because internal anyway it converted to list: `In [17]: %timeit sum(i for i in range(0,1000) if i%3==0 or i%5==0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 230 us per loop`     `In [18]: %timeit sum([i for i in range(0,1000) if i%3==0 or i%5==0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 228 us per loop`

Answer (score -1):

From your code I suppose you need the sum of the numbers which are divisible by `3 or 5`. Among all the solutions, another possible one-liner solution is:

```
print(sum(filter(lambda x: x%3==0 or x%5==0, range(1000))))
```

Here you get this `TypeError` because `sum` function takes a sequence of numbers and returns sum of the sequence. In your code you are passing `i` as the parameter of `sum` which is, in you case, an `int` type object. So you are getting this error.